# Wrapper for DataTable in Visual C#

Tags: c#

In my Visual C# program, I have a `TextBox` with binding to a field in a `DataTable`. That field in the database is encrypted, and I want the application to decrypt the field before showing it in the `TextBox`. As far as I understand it, I need to have a wrapper around the `DataTable` which allows overriding the method that is used to get the value of a field of a `DataRow`, but I don't know how to create it. Please be detailed in your answers, because I'm new to C# programming. An example would be great.

Comment: New to C#-programming and already using databases and encryption? What can we assume you know..?

Comment: New to C# programming, but long experience in other platforms and languages! Give me an answer, and I will ask you whatever I don't know about it.

Comment: Do you want to be able to update the text and write it back to the database, encrypted?

Comment: @Patrick: No. I just want to decrypt the encrypted data. However, a solution that does both is also welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
...
        this.dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler ( dataGridView1_RowsAdded );
    }

    void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender , DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
        DataGridViewRow row;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < e.RowCount ; i++ ) {
            row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i + e.RowIndex];
            if ( row.IsNewRow )
                continue;
            row.Cells["Encrypted"].Value = ToMD5( "111" );
        }
    }
```

Simplely, you can convert you datasource to List< TmpClass >, TmpClass has a property to get encrypted filed, then set this List as datasource.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you show me how I can do the same thing using a TextBox, not a GridView?

Comment: @xling Could you please provide more information about  (you can convert you datasource to List< TmpClass >) ?

Answer (score -1):

ASPX

```
<%# Decrypt( DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BoundedFieldName")) %>
```

CS

```
protected string Decrypt(object encryptedStr){
  // decode}
```

Comment: That is for webforms. I'm talking about winforms.