# Encrypt and decrypt a Datatable in C# without iterating

Tags: c#, encryption, datatable

I need to encrypt and store a datatable in a database (like MS Access or SQL Server). Then read this database and decrypt the data in memory for query on that. How can I do that without iterating over every cell with for or loop?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317179/wrapper-for-datatable-in-visual-c-sharp/6333324#6333324) that (you can convert datasource to `List<TmpClass>`), but I don't know how?

Comment: You need to do research on database encryption and use that learning. There are more than one ways to achieve this. You need to read and decide which one to use.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya , I can use simple encryption methods in c# but I don't know how to convert datasource to List<TmpClass > when TmpClass in encryption class

Comment: Can you share the code of how you get the data source? Is the data source encrypted? If you have a datatable, then you need to iterate thru the rows of it and create object of TempClass for each row and set it's property from the row and add the object to the list.

Comment: Did you read https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/ to understand how to convert datatable to a generic list?

Comment: Many databases will have options to encrypt data at rest, which to me would seem to be a much easier and probably more secure solution.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks for your attention, in (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/) where is my encryption method ?

Comment: @KenY-N Could you provide me more information? Or a link?

Comment: That link is to learn how to convert datatable to list. You can decrypt or encrypt data of datatable while iterating thru rows of datatable.

Answer (score 1):

This largely depends on the technology stack.

For example, take a look at the always on option of the SQL server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider?view=sql-server-ver15

> Always Encrypted allows client applications to encrypt sensitive data and never reveal the data or the encryption keys to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database. An Always Encrypted enabled driver, such as the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server, achieves this by transparently encrypting and decrypting sensitive data in the client application

So, this achieves what you want to do without you needing to do anything in your code.

The solution you posted, says that you need to iterate the data source, get the data and have a member that does the description like this:

```
public class EncDataRows {
    public SomeType SomeProperty {get; set;}
    public void DecryptObject() {
        // ENCRYPT LOGIC HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: And What about MS Access?

Comment: Go for encrypted with password files. You can then access them like this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117757/cannot-connect-to-password-encrypted-ms-access-2016-database-using-c-sharp

Comment: I want to encrypt data in tables because if some one has DataBase password can't read data ...

Comment: Then for access, you are out of luck. You need to iterate every column of the datasource. You can't even query that way with queries using like. I can argue though that anyone who has the encryption key can read the data add well. The encryption key could even be your password.